# imagemin plugin throwing ENOENT error on aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, imagemin

I created a lambda function on aws using imangemin and imagemin-optipng nodejs plugin but it is returning me below error:

error: spawn /var/task/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/optipng ENOENT

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3()
var Imagemin = require('imagemin');
var optipng = require('imagemin-optipng');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;

    var srcKey = 
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));

    var params = {Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey};

    s3.getObject(params).promise()
    .then(data => Imagemin.buffer(data.Body, {
             plugins: [
                optipng({ optimizationLevel: 7 })
             ]
        })
    )
    .then(buffer => 
    console.log('done ', buffer)
)
.catch(err => callback(err))

};
```

Comment: Did you install `imagemin-optipng`? If so, recommend you to take a look at this thread: https://github.com/panteng/wechat-h5-boilerplate/issues/5

Comment: @GCSDC : as you can see from my code I am not using gulp-imagemin, I am using imagemin module.
Could you specify the difference between gulp-imagemin and imagemin modules?

Comment: I see it, still the error reported in the thread is the same, and if you replace `gulp-imagemin` with `imagemin`, the procedures on the comments may solve the issue. Not sure what is the difference between both. I think `gulp-imagemin` is simply an implementation of `imagemin` to be run with gulp.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue yesterday, on AWS Lambda. In case someone is also facing it, **and** the development environment is Windows, then I believe this is the solution for you. *(note that here in my example I'm using Serverless Framework for building and deploying, however, the principle should work regardless of the use of Serverless)*

I tried a few different solutions, but the easiest and fastest solution was to install the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and run Serverless Deploy from the Ubuntu terminal on windows.

The issue is that some packages are OS-dependent, meaning that the same package installed on different OSs are going to produce different installations. Therefore your locally build/run works fine because you **installed** the packages on Windows environment and you are **running** the packages code on Windows environment, however, when you deploy to AWS it is now running on Amazon Linux and your packages that are OS-dependent *(like mozjpeg, jpegtran, etc)* are going to fail during the run. So your best shot is to just install the packages, build **and** deploy your project from a Linux environment *(not sure if all Linux distros fit in this statement, but Ubuntu certainly does)*.

**Here's the timeline for what I did:**

> 1. Install and enable the WSL with Ubuntu *(no big deal at all, 10min top, just follow [Microsofts doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10))*
> 2. Open the Ubuntu terminal **as an administrator** *(if you don't run as administrator it won't allow you to properly run "npm install" in the next steps)*
> 3. Make sure everything is updated, just run *"apt install upgrade"*
> 4. Create a folder by running "mkdir *your-folder-name*" *(or just cd directly into your project's original folder, you can do it by Shift+RightClick on the given folder and choosing "Open Linux Shell Here". I preferred to separate it to avoid messing with my original stuff)*
> 5. Get into the newly created folder by running "cd *your-folder-name*"
> 6. Clone your repository into that folder **or** just copy/paste it manually *(to open your current folder from Ubuntu terminal on Windows just run "explorer.exe .")*
> 7. Run the good and old *"npm install"* from the Ubuntu terminal
> 8. Now here's a pitfall, if you have your AWS KEYS/SECRETS on your **.env** file, and you set your serverless.yml file to use the environment variables from the .env file, the next step will fail if you don't have the .env file in place *(and you will only see the real error on CloudWatch because the console logged error in the browser will be a CORS error)*
> 9. Run *"Serverless Deploy"* to deploy your project

That's it.
Took me around 20min to perform this solution while the others, even though some being effective *(like CodeBuild)*, were more confusing therefore more time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

try Reinstall optipng-bin module. or `node ./node_modules/optipng-bin/lib/install.js`